# AppWidgetProvider and ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, appwidgetprovider

I am modifying WeatherListWidget sample Android app. In my case, data points can change on their own - and I would like these changes to be reflected in app widget display without having to click the refresh button.

Is there a tutorial that would explain how to do this? All I really want to do, I think, is force a refresh or an update. (Yes, I am relatively new to Android programming)

Thanks,

[UPDATE]

I am displaying values for internal sensors (those managed by SensorManager), and listening for sensor value changes. My SensorDataProvider class extends ContentProvider and implements SensorEventListener.

So, this is what will be triggering need for updates of display. Ultimately, I may need to govern the update rate - but that is not my immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an automated refresh time in your widget manifest, that goes as low as 30 minutes.

If you want to update faster than that you can use something like an `AlarmManager` and a `Service` to update the app in more frequent intervals, consider though that this will have an impact on the user's battery life.

This widget has a good example on how to update an app more frequently with a service and a thread. [Google Code Project here.](http://code.google.com/p/24clock/)